# How to center paragraph vertically and horizontally w/ other criteria?

Tags: html, css, center, paragraph

So I have been working on my first website, and I'm having lots of fun doing it.

However, I have found it very difficult to achieve centering a paragraph (spanning more than one line) vertically and horizontally inside of it's div container.

The div has a proportional width (96%), and it is not set by pixels. Also, the paragraph has a set amount of padding (ex: 20px top and bottom).

Is there a trick to center vertically and horizontally in this situation?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: margin:auto for the horizontal part, for the vertical part, **we need your HTML and CSS** to evaluate solutions avalaible in your case or advise to do so

Comment: I'm not currently at my computer, but here is some very similar code: <div class="text_container><p>Text text text...</p></div>                .text_container { height: 500px; width: 96%; margin: 0 auto; } .text_container p { width: 80%; margin-top: 20px/5% (pixels or percentage); margin-bottom: 20px/5% }      Sorry if this looks awful. I typed it on my phone. I'll put up the actual code when I get home!

Comment: Here is a fiddle with two paragraphs, centered horizontally - the upper one using <p>, the lower using a <div> - http://jsfiddle.net/eA5AT/. Here is a fiddle with the text in the "middle" http://jsfiddle.net/eA5AT/1/ - but would need to be adjusted according to the length of the text.

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zv2Pu/1/

I have centered `p` both horizontally and vertically within the `div` container.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

From you 2 examples:

### a single container inside a sized box:

you can use a pseudo to vertical-align pseudo and inside boxe aside each others
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eA5AT/2/)**

```
.holder {
    width: 96%;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
}
.holder:before {
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.holder p {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 20% auto;
    text-align:left;
}
```

### A single or several boxes inside a sized box:

you can use `display:table-cell;`  **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eA5AT/3/)**

```
.holder {
    width: 96%;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:table-cell;/* it will expand if content grows oversized */
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.holder p {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.holder div {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have simply used text-align: center; on your div.