# How can I align text in custom paragraph elements?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align my text to center in my CSS stylesheet. I can't see where I am going wrong.

When I open my document on Google the paragraph text changes colour, font and style but the text alignment does not change

```css
body {
  background-color: floralwhite;
}

h1 {
  color: black;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 300%;
  text-align: center;
}

p1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: lightseagreen;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 120%;
}

p2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: deeppink;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

```html
<h1> Header 1 </h1>
<br/>
<center>
  <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FOXJdP7O6jg">
        </iframe>
</center>
<br/>
<br/>
<p1><b>This text should be bold </b>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
  make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p1>
<br/>
<br/>
<p2><b>This is Paragraph two we wil look</b></p2>
```

Comment: as you are using custom elements for your paragraphs, the browser has interpreted them as inline elements and as such you will need to add display block to them in order  for the text-align center to work.  Instead of doing that, use a proper p tag and give it a class and style the class (also the [center tag is obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#center) and should not be used - use css instead)

Comment: You'll want to have a look at some modern tutorials and documentation. Stick to elements you find on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: Protip: Don't use line breaks for spacing. That's not their purpose. Use margin and padding.

Comment: @I.sh., that question is about centering _elements_. This one is about centering _text_.

Comment: @OrisSin, do not correct code in question posts. That obscures the problems we're being asked to solve.

Comment: So, this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667602/how-to-center-paragraph-vertically-and-horizontally-w-other-criteria

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS you have defined two different style classes for your paragraphs: `p1` and `p2`. However, in your HTML file, you are using different tags for your paragraphs, i.e. `<p1>` and `<p2>`, which are not standard HTML elements.

You can fix this by using the standard `<p>` element in your HTML file, and then applying your styles to the `<p>` element in your CSS.

Example:

```css
body {
  background-color: floralwhite;
}

h1 {
  color: black;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 300%;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 120%;
}

p.p1 {
  color: lightseagreen;
}

p.p2 {
  color: deeppink;
}
```

```html
<h1> Header 1 </h1>
<br/>
<center>
  <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FOXJdP7O6jg">
        </iframe>
</center>
<br/>
<br/>
<p class="p1"><b>This text should be bold </b>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
  make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
<br/>
<br/>
<p class="p2"><b>This is Paragraph two we wil look</b></p>
```

Comment: You wouldn't want to center _every_ paragraph in a document.